# Vertically Center Two Side-By-Side Text Columns of Different Heights

Tags: html, css

Hello i am trying to get something like this,
[image]

**UPDATED:**
Pic Explanation:
The two single cut lines must be of equal length and the double cut lines must be equal too. The distance between both text columns should be related to the center for the sake of bigger screens.

I tried using the following code to achieve this, but it is producing issues when the screen size changes.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% aqua; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<div style="position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
  <div style="float: left; padding-right: 10%;">Some Text Long</div>
  <div style="float: right; padding-left: 10%; border-left: 1px solid red;">Some other long text</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me know if it was what you were after, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need here is the [`box-sizing` CSS rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). In [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xfa77GpW0IVMllc35Agk), I use this rule to evenly space the columns, then make the border appear on all columns except the first:

```
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 3%;
}

.col:first-of-type {
  border-left: none;
}

.col-2 .col {
  width: 44%;

}
```

Here's the html:

```
<div class="col-wrapper col-2">
  <div class="col">Text</div>
  <div class="col">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
</div>
```

Handling the absolute positioning is easy as long as the absolute-ly positioned element has a fixed with:

```
.panel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @walter! Just made few changes in you code and got exactly what i needed! http://jsfiddle.net/y2qe494t/5/ :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **display:table;** and **display:table-cell;** in order to vertical align centrally. 
and you need to add also **height:100%** to html and body and also to .containbox to make the box expand to the full height of the page:

```
html,body{
    min-height:100%; 
    height:100%;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}

.containbox{    
    display:table;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
 }

.leftbox, .rightbox{ 
    width:50%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:2%;}

.rightbox{
    border-left:1px solid black;
 }

/* Remove comments to use another way to create the divider

.rightbox::before{ 
    content: "|";
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
}
*/
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/y2qe494t/3/

In this other demo there is a div .center of 1% width with a divider so not to expand full height.

**DEMO2** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/y2qe494t/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use this HTML

```
<div class="containbox">
  <div class="leftbox">Some Text Long</div>
  <div class="rightbox">Some other long text</div>
</div>
```

and this CSS

```
.containbox{display:block}
.leftbox, .rightbox{display:inline-block; width:45%; height:100%; text-align:center; padding:2%;}
.rightbox{border-left:1px solid #000}
```

and please don't use inline CSS, it's a very bad practice, use class names instead

You can **[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/y2qe494t/)**

Comment: Thanks for replying, i wrote that code in browser so... And another thing, i want that text in absolute vertical center of screen and with padding from center because it looks odd on high resolution machine.